# How to disable address bar search option in Firefox

Tags: firefox, search, address-bar

I couldn't access subfolders in my wamp www directory through Firefox 12.0 a few days ago by typing this in the address bar:

```
http://localhost/folder/subfolder
```

Firefox 12.0 starts Google search when I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>,  and I tried a workaround to disable address bar search by doing this:

```
about:config -> keyword.URL ; set the string as none.
```

Now I can access the subfolders. I know it is not the proper way to do it, but I'd like to know if somebody has a better idea.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I disable searching and domain guessing from the Firefox Address Bar, while keeping other features?](http://superuser.com/questions/389136/how-can-i-disable-searching-and-domain-guessing-from-the-firefox-address-bar-wh)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should go to `keyword.enabled`. Then double-click on it to set its value to **false**.

Comment: And additionally probably set `browser.fixup.alternate.enabled` to `false`, which was what I needed for my Firefox 51.