# How can I prevent firefox/chrome automatically googling a host instead of connecting to it?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I want to type be able to type in a hostname and have firefox lookup that host, or fail.
I don't want it to start automatically searching for said host.

How can I prevent firefox and chrome from searching for things if it can't resolve them with DNS?

NB: Setting `keyword.enabled` in firefox just breaks things more. It doesn't prevent `go` being turned into `go.com`, but it does mean that typing `?foo` will no longer use the default search with the keyword `foo`.

Comment: http://www.h3xed.com/web-and-internet/fix-firefox-33-address-bar-searching-instead-of-resolving-custom-domain-hosts

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Neither 1) nor 3) prevent FF turning `go` or `http://go` into `go.com`

Comment: not a real solution but a workaround - I used to have this problem when accessing my router - so I created a browser-bookmark and named it like the address - this way I get the recommended site when typing in the address and not a google search

Comment: @Squidly: That's a different "feature": http://www-archive.mozilla.org/docs/end-user/domain-guessing.html  http://superuser.com/questions/389136/how-can-i-disable-searching-and-domain-guessing-from-the-firefox-address-bar-wh